# how to jump down the web page with out it deleting the rest of the site?

Tags: javascript, css, html, aptana

here is my site: http://web.njit.edu/~dp257/boilerplate/Org.html
click on the side bar world wide web, all i want it to do is scroll down or jump down the page to that Div(worldwideweb definition) but instead it like deletes the rest of the page except for that div. how come?

heres my website code:

```
          <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="name" align="center">IS117 TERMS</header>
         <div id="primary_links" align="center">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="website.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="CSS.html">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="HTML.html">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="Org.html">Organizations</a></li>
                <li><a href="Tech.html">Technologies</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>

            <div id="content">
                <h1>Organizations</h1>

        <div> 
            Client- the computers and devices that use web applications
        </div> 
        <div> 
            Internet exchange point-a point in the world that connect many WAN’s 
        </div> 
        <div> 
            Internet- global system of interconnected networks
        </div> 
        <div> 
        Internet service provider- Someone or company who owns a WAN and leases its access to their network
        </div> 
        <div> 
            Intranet- network where only employees can run web applications typically they are in the same area
        </div> 
       <div> 
            Local area network- a small network of computers that are near each other and communicate over short distances
        </div> 
        <div> 
            Network-a system that allows clients and servers to communicate
        </div> 
        <div> 
            W3C-world wide web consortium, group that develops standards, for code
        </div> 
        <div> 
            Web browser-programs that access web pages
        </div> 
        <div> 
            Web server- holds the files that make up a web application
        </div> 

        <div> 
            WHATWG-community of people interested in evolving html, big source of info
        </div> 
        <div> 
            Wide area network-2 or more LAN’s connected by a router
        </div> 
        <div id="zz">
            World Wide Web- components that bring together a web page to your desktop over the internet
        </div>



        </div> <!-- content -->


    <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="secondary_links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Client</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Internet Exchange Point</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Internet Service Provide</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intranet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Local Area Network</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Network</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">W3C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Browser</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Server</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WHATWG</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wide Area Network</a></li>
            <li><a href="#zz">World Wide Web</a></li>               
        </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of funky stuff going on in that page.  I recommend starting with just validating the HTML.  You can validate it here - http://html5.validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.njit.edu%2F%7Edp257%2Fboilerplate%2FOrg.html Don't worry about the "X-UA-Compatible" error, but you should definitely get the others fixed and then go from there.